# javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: unable to find LoginModule class: org.jboss.security.ClientLoginModule

Tags: deployment, jenkins, build, jboss5.x

Its been more than 3 days couldn't figure out what is wrong with my Jenkins.

I have Jenkins job, which pull the source from `Bitbucket` and build and Deploy in `Jboss 5.1`.

But at the time of deployment I am getting the bellow exception tried multiple solution but I am getting the same annoying error.

**Stack-trace**

```html
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.534 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-07-08T03:19:04+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/176M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/SpringHelloWorld/workspace/pom.xml to com.programcreek/HelloWorld/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/HelloWorld-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/SpringHelloWorld/workspace/target/HelloWorld.war to com.programcreek/HelloWorld/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/HelloWorld-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
channel stopped
Deploying /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/SpringHelloWorld/workspace/target/HelloWorld.war to container JBoss 5.x Remote
  The undeployment phase of the redeploy action has failed: org.codehaus.cargo.util.CargoException: Cannot undeploy deployable org.codehaus.cargo.container.deployable.WAR[HelloWorld.war]
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
org.codehaus.cargo.util.CargoException: Cannot deploy deployable org.codehaus.cargo.container.deployable.WAR[HelloWorld.war]
 at org.codehaus.cargo.container.jboss.JBoss5xRemoteDeployer.deploy(JBoss5xRemoteDeployer.java:216)
 at org.codehaus.cargo.container.spi.deployer.AbstractDeployer.redeploy(AbstractDeployer.java:212)
 at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:73)
 at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:116)
 at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:103)
 at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:989)
 at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:967)
 at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:103)
 at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:61)
 at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
 at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:761)
 at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:721)
 at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1053)
 at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:670)
 at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1766)
 at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:537)
 at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
 at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:374)
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: unable to find LoginModule class: org.jboss.security.ClientLoginModule
 at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:800)
 at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:203)
 at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:690)
 at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:688)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:687)
 at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:595)
 at org.codehaus.cargo.tools.jboss.JBossDeployer.getDeploymentManager(JBossDeployer.java:176)
 at org.codehaus.cargo.tools.jboss.JBossDeployer.deploy(JBossDeployer.java:71)
 at org.codehaus.cargo.container.jboss.JBoss5xRemoteDeployer.deploy(JBoss5xRemoteDeployer.java:212)
 ... 17 more
javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: unable to find LoginModule class: org.jboss.security.ClientLoginModule
 at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:800)
 at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:203)
 at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:690)
 at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:688)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:687)
 at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:595)
 at org.codehaus.cargo.tools.jboss.JBossDeployer.getDeploymentManager(JBossDeployer.java:176)
 at org.codehaus.cargo.tools.jboss.JBossDeployer.deploy(JBossDeployer.java:71)
 at org.codehaus.cargo.container.jboss.JBoss5xRemoteDeployer.deploy(JBoss5xRemoteDeployer.java:212)
 at org.codehaus.cargo.container.spi.deployer.AbstractDeployer.redeploy(AbstractDeployer.java:212)
 at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:73)
 at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:116)
 at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:103)
 at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:989)
 at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:967)
 at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:103)
 at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:61)
 at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
 at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:761)
 at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:721)
 at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1053)
 at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:670)
 at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1766)
 at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:537)
 at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
 at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:374)
Build step 'Deploy war/ear to a container' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

**I tried multiple ways.**

1. After searching a lot what I found
   `jbossx/jbossx-security-client.jar.zip` is missing in jboss lib, so
   i downloaded the jar and pasted into the lib.
   **But the problem is still there**
   I tried to modify `login-config.xml` but this is also not working for me.

**The content of `login-config.xml` look like this.**

```html
<?xml version='1.0'?>

<!-- The XML based JAAS login configuration read by the
org.jboss.security.auth.login.XMLLoginConfig mbean. Add
an application-policy element for each security domain.

The outline of the application-policy is:
<application-policy name="security-domain-name">
  <authentication>
    <login-module code="login.module1.class.name" flag="control_flag">
      <module-option name = "option1-name">option1-value</module-option>
      <module-option name = "option2-name">option2-value</module-option>
      ...
    </login-module>

    <login-module code="login.module2.class.name" flag="control_flag">
      ...
    </login-module>
    ...
  </authentication>
</application-policy>

$Id: login-config.xml 87078 2009-04-09 14:23:47Z bstansberry@jboss.com $
$Revision: 87078 $
-->

<policy>
  <!-- Used by clients within the application server VM such as
  mbeans and servlets that access EJBs.
  -->
  <application-policy name="client-login">
    <authentication>
      <login-module code="org.jboss.security.ClientLoginModule"
        flag="required">
         <!-- Any existing security context will be restored on logout -->
         <module-option name="restore-login-identity">true</module-option>
      </login-module>
    </authentication>
  </application-policy>

  <!-- Security domains for testing new jca framework -->
  <application-policy name="HsqlDbRealm">
    <authentication>
      <login-module code="org.jboss.resource.security.ConfiguredIdentityLoginModule"
        flag="required">
        <module-option name="principal">sa</module-option>
        <module-option name="userName">sa</module-option>
        <module-option name="password"></module-option>
        <module-option name="managedConnectionFactoryName">jboss.jca:service=LocalTxCM,name=DefaultDS</module-option>
      </login-module>
    </authentication>
  </application-policy>

  <application-policy name="JmsXARealm">
    <authentication>
      <login-module code="org.jboss.resource.security.ConfiguredIdentityLoginModule"
        flag="required">
        <module-option name="principal">guest</module-option>
        <module-option name="userName">guest</module-option>
        <module-option name="password">guest</module-option>
        <module-option name="managedConnectionFactoryName">jboss.jca:service=TxCM,name=JmsXA</module-option>
      </login-module>
    </authentication>
  </application-policy>

  <!-- A template configuration for the jmx-console web application. This
    defaults to the UsersRolesLoginModule the same as other and should be
    changed to a stronger authentication mechanism as required.
  -->
  <application-policy name="jmx-console">
    <authentication>
      <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsersRolesLoginModule"
        flag="required">
        <module-option name="usersProperties">props/jmx-console-users.properties</module-option>
        <module-option name="rolesProperties">props/jmx-console-roles.properties</module-option>
      </login-module>
    </authentication>
  </application-policy>

  <!-- A template configuration for the web-console web application. This
    defaults to the UsersRolesLoginModule the same as other and should be
    changed to a stronger authentication mechanism as required.
  -->
  <application-policy name="web-console">
    <authentication>
      <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsersRolesLoginModule"
        flag="required">
        <module-option name="usersProperties">web-console-users.properties</module-option>
        <module-option name="rolesProperties">web-console-roles.properties</module-option>
      </login-module>
    </authentication>
  </application-policy>

  <!--
    A template configuration for the JBossWS security domain.
    This defaults to the UsersRolesLoginModule the same as other and should be
    changed to a stronger authentication mechanism as required.
  -->
  <application-policy name="JBossWS">
    <authentication>
      <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsersRolesLoginModule"
        flag="required">
        <module-option name="usersProperties">props/jbossws-users.properties</module-option>
        <module-option name="rolesProperties">props/jbossws-roles.properties</module-option>
        <module-option name="unauthenticatedIdentity">anonymous</module-option>
      </login-module>
    </authentication>
  </application-policy>

  <!-- The default login configuration used by any security domain that
  does not have a application-policy entry with a matching name
  -->
  <application-policy name="other">
    <!-- A simple server login module, which can be used when the number
    of users is relatively small. It uses two properties files:
    users.properties, which holds users (key) and their password (value).
    roles.properties, which holds users (key) and a comma-separated list of
    their roles (value).
    The unauthenticatedIdentity property defines the name of the principal
    that will be used when a null username and password are presented as is
    the case for an unuathenticated web client or MDB. If you want to
    allow such users to be authenticated add the property, e.g.,
    unauthenticatedIdentity="nobody"
    -->
    <authentication>
      <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsersRolesLoginModule"
        flag="required"/>
    </authentication>
  </application-policy>

</policy>
```

I am not sure what do I do with this file.
Does anybody have any clue regarding this ??

Comment: Stuck at the same problem. Will ping if I find something. Or will come back if you found something. :)

Comment: did u get any thing..?? I am stuck there any hint?

Comment: I added `jboss-6.0.0.Final/client/jbosssx-as-client.jar` and `jboss-6.0.0.Final/client/jbosssx-client.jar` to `.jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib` and now the error is `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jboss.security.ClientLoginModule` which means the class is found but there is something else that is preventing it from getting loaded. Digging further. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: After searching a lot, what i found that Deploy plug-in it self has a problem. so I used another method to do so. Since we are able to build the project, what we are left with is to only deploy the project in the Jboss. so instead of using deploy plug-in I am using shell script. "SCP" to copy the .war file in Jboss deploy folder and restart the jboss with shell script as well

Comment: I arrived at the same conclusion. But can you tell how do you manage to restart a remote jboss from within jenkins? SCP is easy enough to do, but a restart?

Comment: Which version of Jboss are you using it??

Comment: and one more thing if do not restart your jboss, it will automatically UP your project. just try it

Comment: Bro did you try it. i'll add the answer because this problem sucks. I dont want other to waste their time on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a lot, what I found that `Deploy plug-in` it self has a problem. so I used another method to do so. Since, we are able to build the project, what  are we left with is to only deploy the project in the `Jboss`. So instead of using `deploy plug-in` I am using shell script. "SCP" to copy the .war file in Jboss deploy folder and restart the jboss with shell script as well.

And its done